# Do something with returned value

Tags: vb.net

I have written a function that tells you its function itselfs as you read it:

```
Public Function TestConnect()
    Dim verbinding As MySqlConnection
    Dim errStatus As String

    verbinding = New MySqlConnection()
    verbinding.ConnectionString = "server=" & vardbHost & "; port=" & vardbPort & "; uid=" & vardbUser & "; pwd=" & vardbPass & "; database=" & vardbName & ";"

    Try
        verbinding.Open()
        verbinding.Close()
        errStatus = 0
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        verbinding.Dispose()
        verbinding.Close()
        errStatus = 1
    End Try

    Return errStatus
End Function
```

Now I call this function in my main form and I thought that if I used Try and then catch the 1 or 0 then I could do something with it. (eg. Display a form with the error message) but that does not seem to work and I could not find anything on Google that applies to my problem.

Could anybody explain to me why I am so dumb and how I could better understand how to handle a returned value?

Comment: Hmm. A string variable, that is assigned integers, that represent booleans, that gets returned as an Object.

Comment: Can you show us the code that call this function? What do you receive in response?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the TestFunction. Also define in what way it doesn't work (exception etc)

Comment: I just dim my class `Dim SQLHook As New Database.MySQLHook()` and then in my frmMain.Load I call it as `SQLHook.TestConnect()`. As you can see the code, if the connection is succesfull, the application gives you 0, if there is a error, it tells you 1. I want display a message in my frmMain when the TestConnect function returns a 1 and display a Dialog when it returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function will be returning your value, but you need to get that assign that returned value to a variable, and then make use of it in your Calling method, eg:

```
Dim errStatus As Integer
errStatus = SQLHook.TestConnect()
If errStatus = 1 Then
    'Show the error form
End If
```

Or more briefly, just test the returned value directly:

```
If SQLHook.TestConnect()= 1 Then
    'Show the error form
End If
```

You should also really sort out the variable typing in your function:

```
Public Function TestConnect() as Boolean
    Dim errStatus As Boolean
    Try
        errStatus = True
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        errStatus = False
    End Try

    Return errStatus  
End Function
```

or even more simply, don't bother with the variable:

```
Public Function TestConnect() as Boolean

    Try
        ...
        Return True
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        ...
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: I learned something today. I need to set a variable in order to get the value. Thank you Jon.

Comment: One more thing, you need to switch the order of the `Dispose` and the `Close` in your catch block

Comment: @RicardoJacobs Actually, if you need that value only one time, you do not need a variable, you can simply write `If (SQLHook.TestConnect() = 1) Then ...`.

Comment: @Teejay: I've got that covered!

Comment: @RicardoJacobs But, if you need the value *n*-times, you **do** need a variable. In fact, if you don't use a variable in that case, you'll execute *n*-times the function.

Comment: @JonEgerton Yes, you covered it but Ricardo wrote "*I learned something today. I need to set a variable in order to get the value*"

Comment: @JonEgerton Thank you for the `Dispose` and `Close` warning. It is good to let it check others.

@Teejay I understand your point and I wrote it down. I am going to examine this in some books to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the question, but do you mean something like this?

```
Public Function TestConnect() As Int32
  ...
  Dim errStatus As Int32
  ...
```

Comment: Fair enough, have removed the offending note :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim returnCode as Int32 = SQLHook.TestConnect()

MessageBox.show(
         If(returnCode = 1, "OK", "Error"), "AppName", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
         If(returnCode = 1, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
       )
```